# libtool installed locally, no AC_PROG_LIBTOOL during configure.ac

Tags: makefile, autotools, configure, libtool

I have installed libtool locally:

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/libtool
make
make install
/path/to/libtool/bin/libtool --finish /path/to/libtool

export PATH=/path/to/libtool/bin:$PATH
```

Then, I (I am trying to install expat locally) go to the expat directory and run:

```
./buildconf.sh
```

I get two errors:

```
// this probably doesn't matter, since I am in a linux env
error: possibly undefined macro: AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_DLL 

// this seems to point to my libtools install:
error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
```

Note that libtool is in the path, if I run:

```
$ libtool --version

// outputs:
libtool (GNU libtool) 2.4.6
Written by Gordon Matzigkeit, 1996

Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

There seems to be some sort of local linkage step that I need to perform, but I am having trouble discovering what it is on google.

How do I populate/link the libtool macro? What could be going wrong with my install?

Comment: do you have autoconf installed?

Comment: @arved yes, this is also local, so I assume I have environment issues

Comment: Try this: export AUTOM4TE=/path/to/local/autom4te